columns order in custom index in timescale hypertables
in their documentation after creating the hypertable with
SELECT create_hypertable('stocks_real_time', by_range('time'));

they suggest creating an index that have time component beside commonly queried column
CREATE INDEX ix_symbol_time ON stocks_real_time (symbol, time DESC);

typically in other databases the partition key (in this case time) has to be a prefix of the index.
why timescale do not mention this and only require it having time column in the index
without being a prefix.

It all depends on your specific queries, there is no generic advice for what index works best in all situations

@FrankHeikens I'm talking about the same example in their document, a stock price over time, partitioned by time, indexed by symbol.

It doesn't say that it requires the time column in the index.  It just offers one example, which happened to have that column and happened to have it 2nd.  Why would it discuss the recommendations/documentation of unrelated products at all?  Since a column named "symbol" is unlikely to be searched by range or inequality, while one named "time" is likely to be searched by range or inequality, it makes more sense for symbol to be first, regardless of extension or partitioning.

@jjanes quote "as long as you include the time column", the question is should time be first or last because there seems to be conflicting information

@MuayyadAlsadi I don't know what the quote in your docs link in the comment is supposed to convey, but experimentally it is not necessary to include "time" in the index.  Maybe that line is left over from older versions where it was necessary.  The accepted answer at that other link just doesn't make sense. The planner will automatically rule out partitions which can't match, there is no need for the time column to be in a certain location in the index, or even in the index at all, to make that happen.
